# Create profile Urls in django

Tags: django, redirect, custom-url

I am trying to make my first ever Django app. I have made a simple form where a user can enter a `username`. When the user clicks on submit, I want to redirect him to the url containing that `username`.

For example, Lets say my form is in the url `www.mydomain.com/form`

if the user enters the `username = 'myname`, I want to take him to the url `www.mydomain.com/myname` and display `Hello myname, Welcome to www.mydomain.com`.

Any idea how can I achieve that?

## Edit

here is what i am currently doing

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'temp.views.home',name='home'),
    url(r'^temp/$', 'temp.views.temp',name='temp'),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<entry>[A-Za-z0-9_.\-~]+)','temp.views.mimic',name='mimic'),
]
```

### views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
    def home(request):
        return render(request,'home.html',{})

    def temp(request):
        entry=request.POST['entry']
        print entry
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/entry/"+entry)

    def mimic(request,entry):
        return HttpResponse(entry)
```

### home.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/temp/">{% csrf_token %}
<INPUT name='entry'>
<input type='submit' text='done'>
</form>
```

Now my question is can i somehow avoid this *temp* part in both urls and views n do the whole redirection in one step?

P.S. i know that i need to define a few checks on the form. I will add them later. currently lets assume that the entry made by the user matches with the regex defined in the url

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you are having difficulty with this. Getting the data from the form? redirecting? what?

Comment: Could be helpful if you post some code.

Comment: what did you try so far? with some specific bug would be easier to figure out what you are missing

Comment: If you don't want a separate temp view, why don't you do that in the index view?

Comment: I'm guessing you created a temp app? You don't need to do that. What are you trying to achieve in this application? If you are just trying to learn the language, your use case is not one that is well suited to learning Django.

Answer (score 1):

What you need:

- a Form Class for input of the profile name

  - `name = forms.CharField(...)`
  - a `clean_name(self)` method raising `ValidationError` for unknown profiles
- a view myformview

  - with displays the form for GET-Requests
  - validates the form for POST-Requests and then uses `django.shortcuts.redirect` with your profile view and the name.
- your profile view of course

Comment: can you be a little more specific n give me the exact view function if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure of the following:

- that your form is actually creating a profile record
- that the view that generates the form also verifies its input and saves the model record
- that your profile model is set up with an absolute url, so you can redirect to its page
- that the view that processes the form then redirects the user to the absolute url for the created model
- that you have set up the corresponding `urlpattern` so that requests to 
  `/<username>/` points to a detail view you have set up for the profile model

If you are confused by any of these steps, I strongly consider that you find a Django tutorial that appeals to you and follow it exactly. It will instruct you on performing all of the steps above.

Comment: i have edited my question. can you now be a little more specific?

Comment: The answer is that you must get your hands on a good Django book and follow the steps properly. You are not using a form and you do not have any kind of view that processes form input correctly. There is no meaningful way to get the code you have written to do what you want. Instead you need to start over and use the frameworks and practices that are expected when programming in Django.